# “Never alter or delete a user’s work without them knowing” - is there a name for this software design principle?

Tags: design-patterns, design-principles, least-astonishment

Is there a software design principle that says an application should never alter or delete a user’s work done in the application without them knowing?

It’s very similar to the **Principle of Least Astonishment**, but specifically referring to modifying a user’s data. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment

For a random example off the top of my head, imagine an image-editing application brightening or darkening an image (without informing the user) every time they save it, to offset their desktop gamma settings.

Comment: It's either itself called POLA or is a part of the more generalized idea that is called that. There isn't a more specific phrase for it.

Comment: There is no such design principle. If you contribute to a project, you have the authority to change whatever you like and have it approved by whomever is a co-contributor, with or without the knowledge of the original author of the part you are changing.

Comment: @Bohemian, if you contribute to a project, you may choose to apply or ignore any design principle. But the choice of application has no effect on a principle's mere existence. I don't see how this comment relates to the question.